# Second order, homogeneous, linear ODE with non-constant $y$ coefficient and 0 $y'$ coefficient. "Pendulum-like" problem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

I am solving the following equation:

$$y''(\theta)=f(\theta) y(\theta)$$

The only way of tackling this problem I thought of was to expand $f(\theta)$ as a Taylor or possibly Fourier series, but I'm fairly confident there must be a tone of resources regarding this general problem.

Could anyone post some references or maybe have a go at this equation? $\theta$ is the radial variable which ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$ and the solution should be as optimal as possible in this domain assuming an arbitrary, known function $f$.

Regards,
Michal

UPDATE:

Thanks to [Tamim](http://hhttps://math.stackexchange.com/users/726500/tamim)'s insight I menaged to rephrase the problem as a system of first order linear ODE's for $w(\theta)=(y(\theta),y'(\theta))$. We have then
$$w(\theta)'=A(\theta)w(\theta)$$
for $A(\theta)=((0,1),(f(\theta),0)$. This can be solved exactly using the [Magnus Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_expansion).

Following the procedure described in the article let's us compute $y(\theta)$ up to some order $k$ in the expansion. I am still interested in other approaches though, so if anyone has something to share on this topic, I will be grateful.

Thanks, Michał

Comment: One of the possible routes would be the application of Abel's Identity to identify one of the solutions knowing the other, but I don't know if we can say anything more than that if we don't know one of the solutions.

Comment: Couldn’t you re-write the second order equation into a system of first order equations and try to solve $$\frac{dw}{dx}=A(x)w(x)$$ where $w(x)=(y(x), v(x))$ and $$A(x)=[0, 1;f(x),0]$$

Comment: Yes, indeed. Do I simply diagonalise A(x) then? I'm sorry but I'm unfamiliar with the theory for non-constant coefficients.

Comment: The standard technique I know would be to find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $A$ and then to express $w$ as a sum of exponentials, but this doesn't hold for a generic $f$ i pressume

Comment: You are right, I haven’t found any information on the general solution but for some specific matrixes there is a method called “Magnus expansion”. Basically if $A(x_1)A(x_2)=A(x_2)A(x_1)$ then the above mentioned method should work.

Comment: Ahhh, we are getting somewhere. I will make a follow-up question tomorrow, since it's quite late where I live, but the "Magnus expansion" sounds very promising. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help! Good night

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Airy functions

The most simple case of a (properly) second order DE with non-constant coefficients is 
$$
y''(x)=xy(x).
$$
It does not have solutions in elementary or "standard library" functions, but its solutions are named as "Airy functions" (of the first and second type).

#### Hill equation

From your remarks and comments it appears as if $f$ is intended to be a periodic function. Equations
$$
y''(x)=f(x)y(x)
$$
with periodic $f$ (minimal period $\pi$, but that can be arranged by rescaling the time variable) are called [Hill equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_differential_equation). As you can read on the wikipedia page, there is a solution theory, [Floquet theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory) that describes solutions as (combinations of) products of exponential and periodic factors. The periodic contents can be analyzed via Fourier series, where solutions are characterized via Hill determinants.

#### [Mathieu](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2858213/115115) [equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3497182/115115)

These special cases of the Hill equation that are small periodic perturbations of the harmonic oscillator 
$$
y''(x)+[ω^2+2ϵ\cos(2x)]y(x)=0
$$
that are especially well-suited to explore the resulting resonance cases. Essentially around $ω=k\in\Bbb N$ in a region of size $O(ϵ^k)$ there is resonance growing (initially) in a time scale $ϵ^kt$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this input. I think we can conclude this topic now. :)